# How to convert dynamical system to polar coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

I have a dynamical system on the plane given by $$\dot{x}=-y+x\left(1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\\ \\ \dot{y}=y+x\left(1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

I want to convert this into polar coordinates as it will be easier for the question I am attempting to solve (it gives a hint to convert this into polar coordinates).

Problem is I don't know how to do this I know all the relations for polar coordinates to relate it to Cartesian coordinates for example I know the bit in the bracket would be $(1-r)$ but I don't know what $\dot{x}$ would and how to convert it into polar coordinates.

Any help?

Comment: Answer this question: if you know $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ and also know how $r$ and $\phi$ related to $x$ and $y$, can you write $\dot{r}$ and $\dot{\phi}$ ?

Comment: I don't understand sorry.

Comment: What **exactly** you don't understand?

Comment: How to find $\dot{r},\dot{\theta}$

Comment: As you know, $r^2 = x^2+y^2$. What would happen if you calculate time derivative of left and right side of this equality?

Comment: This is what I am struggling to do I don't know how to take the derivative w.r.t. time of both sides? would it be $d(r^2)/dt=d(x^2)/dt+d(y^2)/dt$?

Comment: Yes, that's it. If you don't remember chain rule for derivatives, it's the right time to revise it, because it's used everywhere in differential equations.

Comment: Having just done this calculation I think the original system was missing a bracket. The solution is much nicer if

$$
\dot{x}=\left(-y+x\right)\left(1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\\ \\
\dot{y}=\left(y+x\right)\left(1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 12):

**I suggest that you try to understand how it works in general.**

> $1)$ From $x',y'$ to $r',\theta'$:
>   $$
> r' = \left(\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \right)'
> = \frac{(x^2 +y^2)'}{2
> \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}=\frac{xx' +yy'}{r}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \theta' = \left(\arctan \frac{y}{x} \right)'
> = \frac{(y/x)'}{1+(y/x)^2} = \frac{y' x -x' y}{r^2}.
> $$

Now in the other direction.

> $2)$ From $r',\theta'$ to $x',y'$:
>   $$
> x'= (r\cos\theta)'=r' \cos \theta -r \theta' \sin \theta 
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> y'= (r\sin\theta)'= r' \sin \theta + r \theta' \cos \theta .
> $$

After understanding this you can proceed on your own.